# Count of Request Patterns

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to find the count of request patterns in a requests.log file.The requests.log files has requests in the following format

```
102.232.32.322  "/v1/places?name=ass&lat=22.3&lng=12.12 HTTP 1.1" 23 111
102.232.32.322  "/v1/places/23232 HTTP 1.1" 23 111
102.232.32.322  "/v1/places?name=bcdd&lat=22.23&lng=12.12&quality_score=true HTTP1.1" 23 111
.....
```

I have so far only been able to cut strings and strip out numbers

```
cat requests.log | grep /v1/places | cut -c53- |cut -d '"' -f 1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed 's/[0-9]//g' 

100 /v1/places?name=<name>&lat=<lng>
110 /v1/places/<placeid>
10  /v1/places?name=<name>&lat=<lat>&lng=<&lng>&country_code=<country>
```

in the above fashion for all the possible patterns ignoring the order of request params
The output should be in the following manner

Another major problem is that the parameters orders is not guaranteed

Comment: You may want to move this into a script file because it may get long, but you could use a function to gather parameters as an array, then sort the array (so you don't have to care about order) and store it in a larger array which you can then loop through and count iterations of repeats.

Comment: What do you mean by `request patterns`?

Comment: I mean 
100 /v1/places?name=<anyname>&lat=<any lat>&lng=<any lng>
10 /v1/places/<placeid>

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: Exactly in the above comment
count  followed by request pattern per line

Comment: Comment is NOT the place for it, edit your question and provide it there.

Comment: The output format has been updated

Comment: I fail to see how that string you provided corresponds to a count of `100`.

Comment: That is because the above is just an example of the output format.The command would also not give that output.I am looking forward to get some suggestions of how to improve the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{sub(/^"/, "", $2); a[$2]++} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' OFS='\t' log.file
2   /v1/places/23232
1   /v1/places?name=ass&lat=22.3&lng=12.12
1   /v1/places?name=bcdd&lat=22.23&lng=12.12&quality_score=true
```